# Backbone Collection Will Not Populate

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework

I am a backbone.js beginner and am having trouble geting a very basic dummy example working.  I'm sure it's the result of a stupid mistake, but would appreciate any guidance.

Here is my javascript:

```
var lr = lr || {};

lr.Event = Backbone.Model.extend({});

lr.Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: lr.Event,
  url: '/json/dummy.json'
});

lr.EventView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection = new lr.Events();
    this.collection.fetch();
    console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
  } 
});

lr.ev = new lr.EventView();
```

Here is json/dummy.json:

```
[
  { "title": "Event1", "Location": "New York, NY" },
  { "title": "Event2", "Location": "Cleveland, OH" }
]
```

I would expect this to console.log the JSON, but it instead console.log's an empty array.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually need to wait for the data to be retrieved, because fetching is async. Example in coffescript:

```
collection.fetch({
  success: (model, resp) ->   
     console.log();
})
```